# Extract text in CSS class

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Trying to extract the data from a webpage to table. For e.g.

```
Block Number XXX
Building Name YYY
Street Name zzz
Pin Code 123456789
```

I am trying to get all details of the company in tabular form using this code...

```
html_doc='https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/test.html'

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(html_doc), 'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "row"})

for i in mydivs:
    for x in i.findAll("div", {"class": "col-md-3 col-sm-3"}):
        print (x)
        print ('new x')
```

But I am not sure how to extract the text in HTML tag of a particular CSS class.

Comment: excuse me I remove my answer because you want get the tag from class and not retrieve the class name.

Comment: check [get-text](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the items you need are inside the `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">` tags. And, all the items other than *General Information* follow a specific format: first `div` tag is the label and the second is the corresponding text. So, you can simply find them all and then print them alternately as the label and its text.

So, everything other than the *General Information* is available in the `<div id="fldFirm">` tag. As the *General Information* doesn't follow the above format, you'll have to scrape it individually first. You can get the first *two* tags using `limit=2`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/test.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

gen_info = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find('div', id='divInfoType').find_all('div', class_='col-md-3 col-sm-3', limit=2)]
print('{}: {}'.format(gen_info[0], gen_info[1]))

all_info = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find('div', id='fldFirm').find_all('div', class_='col-md-3 col-sm-3')]

for i in range(0, len(all_info), 2):
    print('{}: {}'.format(all_info[i], all_info[i+1]))
```

Output:

```
Information Type: Other Than Individual
Name: Bellissimo Developers Thane Private Limited (Lodha Developers Pvt Ltd)
Organization Type: Company
Description For Other Type Organization: NA
Do you have any Past Experience ?: No
Block Number: 412, Floor 4 17G
Building Name: Vardhaman Chamber
Street Name: Cawasji Patel Road
Locality: Fort
Land mark: Horniman Circle
State/UT: MAHARASHTRA
Division: Konkan
District: Mumbai City
Taluka: Mumbai City
Village: Mumbai City
Pin Code: 400001
Office Number: 02261334263
Website URL: www.lodhagroup.com
```

**Edit:**

To create a dataframe, you can use this:

```
gen_info = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find('div', id='divInfoType').find_all('div', class_='col-md-3 col-sm-3', limit=2)]
all_info = gen_info + [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find('div', id='fldFirm').find_all('div', class_='col-md-3 col-sm-3')]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': all_info[0::2], 'B': all_info[1::2]})
```

Comment: @shantanuo, actually, the CSS and JS files are not loading on my browser (don't know why, but I'm seeing *403 Forbidden* status code for them) and I'm seeing plain text. So, is this what you were expecting as the output? Actually, only the main *test.html* file is loading. Is this the case on your browser too?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Is it possible to save it as pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are many ways you can do that. Have a look at the edit, I've shown a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want the address information or the whole listing? here is the code for the whole listing.

```
html_doc='https://s3.amazonaws.com/todel162/test.html'

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(html_doc), 'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "form-group"})

for x in mydivs:
    print (re.sub( '\s+', ' ', x.text ).strip())
    print ('#############')
```

Outputs:

```
Information Type Other Than Individual
#############
Name Bellissimo Developers Thane Private Limited (Lodha Developers Pvt Ltd)
#############
Organization Type Company
#############
Do you have any Past Experience ? No
#############
Block Number 412, Floor 4 17G Building Name Vardhaman Chamber
#############
Street Name Cawasji Patel Road Locality Fort
#############
Land mark Horniman Circle State/UT MAHARASHTRA
#############
Division Konkan District Mumbai City
#############
Taluka Mumbai City Village Mumbai City
#############
Pin Code 400001
#############
Office Number 02261334263
#############
Website URL www.lodhagroup.com
#############
```

if you want it in a table (very crude example):

```
...
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "form-group"})
print ("<table>")
for x in mydivs:
    label = x.find('label')
    if label is not None:
        print ("<tr><td>" + label.text + "</td><td> ")
        label.extract()
    else:
        print ("<tr><td></td><td> ")
    print (re.sub( '\s+', ' ', x.text ).strip())
    print ('</td></tr>')
print ("</table>")
```

Outputs:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Information Type</td><td> 
Other Than Individual
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td> 
Bellissimo Developers Thane Private Limited (Lodha Developers Pvt Ltd)
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Organization Type</td><td> 
Company
</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td> 
Do you have any Past Experience ? No
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Block Number</td><td> 
412, Floor 4 17G Building Name Vardhaman Chamber
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Street Name</td><td> 
Cawasji Patel Road Locality Fort
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Land mark</td><td> 
Horniman Circle State/UT MAHARASHTRA
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Division</td><td> 
Konkan District Mumbai City
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Taluka</td><td> 
Mumbai City Village Mumbai City
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Pin Code</td><td> 
400001
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Office Number</td><td> 
02261334263
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Website URL</td><td> 
www.lodhagroup.com
</td></tr>
</table>
```